# WYSIWYG Editor (jHtmlArea enhancement needed)

Tags: jquery, jhtmlarea

Working on a very data-intensive website project with lots of jQuery/JavaScript and we are writing a lot ourselves but also using a number of plugins, but even when we add a plugin we tend to then need to add even more functionality to it. In one instance we need to allow the user to embolden, italicize or underline text they select so we are using the jHtmlArea plugin (http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com) and it does work but we also need to show a character counter on it that respects the maxlength on the associated TEXTAREA element.

I have found a jsfiddle (nXMqc) that has a character counter based on the TEXTAREA maxlength. 
But I need to get it to work with the jHtmlArea plugin. My attempts so far have been fruitless.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle I was talking about that I couldn't link to in my original post: http://jsfiddle.net/nXMqc/

Comment: need to do the counting within the Iframe where WYSIWYG does the editing...  look in plugin code and bind a keyup handler to iframe document

Comment: Have you given my answer a try?

Comment: Charlie, my scripting seems to not be able to affect anything going on in the IFRAME. It's like it has a mind of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to acheive this by updating the javascript in jHtmlArea-0.7.5.js

Particularly, the following:

```
   ...
   updateTextArea: function () {
        this.textarea.val(this.toHtmlString());

        //Add the following javascript
        var val = $(this.textarea).val();
        var vallength = val.length;
        $("#counter-div").html(vallength);

    },...
```

Then you will able to use `<div id="counter-div"></div>` right under your textarea.

There will be some additional modifications if you want to have multiple jHtmlAreas on a single page. Basically `counter-div` will need to be uniquely identified to the textarea you are modifying.

Comment: Thanks. Going to start working this in. Getting to this now because I'm back at work now after the weekend.

Comment: UPDATE: Your addition I think is a definite help but it doesn't count the text that is being entered into the IFRAME that masks over the TEXTAREA as implemented by the jHtmlArea plugin.

Comment: Michael, I see that you are setting a variable called "maxlength" but I don't see where it's being used after that. The other variables do seem to be getting used though.

Comment: I removed it. It was pulled over from the jsfiddle you posted in your first comment.  It would be used to change the color of the counter as you got closer to the limit.  In regards to your second comment, when you enter text into the IFRAME, it should fire updateTextArea. So it will have the same result as you are trying to achieve.  That was my experience anyways, if you need me to provide the full code I used I can.

Comment: The problem seems to be that entering text into the IFRAME does not fire updateTextArea. Here's a fork of the original jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kTrB/ Maybe you can put your working code into a fork of the fork. Thanks for working with me on this.

Comment: It's working like I would expect it to. Are you not seeing it update? or not seeing the update you expect?  Are you only wanting the visible text counted, or the count of the html code?

Comment: I just saw your comments in the jsfiddle. I would recommend not 'trimming' because it would require you to write something that safely extracted the html and then remove empty elements if your trimming creates them. You'd probably end up having large jumps in the text count due to the HTML tags being added and dropped.

Comment: Yeah, I have it working now. The jsfiddle works but there were some minor issues when porting it back into the larger project. Thanks for all the help.